# Cannot create group

Tags: group, suse

When I try to create a group with specified group id `groupadd xyz -g 999` I get the following message: `groupadd: group 'xyz' already exists`. I checked all files `cat /etc/group /etc/group_0 ... | grep xyz` but zero results are found. When I try to delete the group with `groupdel xyz` I get `groupdel: cannot remove entry 'xyz' from /etc/group`. OS: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (x86_64); VERSION = 12

Comment: What command are you running to add the group? Is the group ID you are trying to assign to the group already in use?

Comment: `groupadd -f xyz -g 999`

Comment: and the id is available: `cat /etc/group | grep 999  | wc -l` returns 0

Comment: LDAP or NIS in play here?

Comment: `getent group | grep xyz` ?

Comment: Actually `getent group xyz` returned a record. @steve LDAP plays here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group is held within an external database such as LDAP or NIS, rather than /etc/group.